# Harish-Chandra–Itzykson–Zuber integral with two terms

Tags: st.statistics, random-matrices, statistical-physics

We know
$$
\int \mathcal{D}U \exp(\mathrm{Tr}(AUBU^*))
$$
can be computed by Harish-Chandra–Itzykson–Zuber(HCIZ) integral. I am wondering whether it is possible to compute
$$
I=\int \mathcal{D}U \exp(\mathrm{Tr}(AUBU^*)+\mathrm{Tr}(CUDU^*))?
$$
Or even the limit of this integral when $N\to \infty$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this looks to me like a case of the tensor HCIZ integral discussed in arXiv:2010.13661 and arXiv:2201.12778.